# Passing a model attribute to a Rails view using redirect_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to pass a model attribute to a view, after successfully setting it to a new value from inside an action in my controller. But this variable is always nil by the time it gets to the view, so I can't use it to conditionally display stuff. I should add that this attribute is not a field in the database. What am I missing/doing wrong?

Here is the code in my model:

```
attr_accessor :mode

#getter
def mode
 @mode
end

#setter
def mode=(val)
 @mode = val
end
```

...in the controller:

```
@report.mode = "t"
redirect_to edit_report_path(@report)
```

...and in my view:

```
<%= build_report(@report.mode) %>
```

...but this helper method never gets the variable I just set in the controller.  It is nil. What gives? Clearly I'm missing something basic here because this seems like it should be straightforward. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`edit_report_path` generates a URL with the ID of `@report` in it.

`redirect_to` essentially creates a whole new request, and goes to that URL. When it gets to `edit`, all it has is the ID. Usually that's fine - it looks up the object and keeps going, but of course it's not going to have the non-db field you set.

There are a couple ways to fix this. You can use :render instead to get to the edit page -  then @report will have the field set.

```
@report.mode = "t"
render :action => edit and return
```

Or, you can make `mode` a database field.

Comment: This is what I used:
    render (:action => 'edit', :object => @report) and return
Thanks to all of you...

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is in the `redirect_to`. When you redirect somewhere else all instance variables are lost. So when you set `@report.mode = "t"` it sets the attribute. But when you redirect that data is lost.

I am assuming the `<%= build_report(@report.mode) %>` is in edit_report.html.erb and the code from when you set 'mode' is not in the edit action. If this is the case you may be able to pass the `report.mode` to the edit action in the url like so:

```
 build_report(@report.mode, :mode => "t")
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `redirect_to`; you're returning a response to the client that causes it to redo the request with a different url.  In that second request the mode isn't set because you didn't save it before wrapping up the first request.